# Why in sandbox paypal payouts api always return batch_status pending? But money transfer successfully

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, payout

I just try to implement paypal payout api using sandbox account. All the funcationality works successfully, like money send from admin account to another account via email. But it always return **batch_status pending** on sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal functionality. Batches begin in a pending state and will complete when all their payments complete or fail.

If you need to be notified automatically when batches finish, [there are webhooks for such events](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#batch-payouts).